# Add an AdView in this Adapter

Tags: android, listview, admob

I want to add an adview on the second position in this adapter. What do I have to change for that? I tried a lot in the last two hours. Can I insert this after loading the list?

Here is my code from the adapter:

```
public class FeedsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FeedsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<FeedItem> feedItems;
    MainActivity context;
    private static final String FILENAME = "prefsSettings";
    private static final String VAL_KEY7 = "news_format";

    public FeedsAdapter(MainActivity context, ArrayList<FeedItem> feedItems) {
        this.feedItems = feedItems;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(FILENAME, 0);
        String theme = sharedPrefs.getString(VAL_KEY7, "little");
        View view = null;
        if(theme.equals("big")) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custum_row_news_item, parent, false);
        } else if (theme.equals("little")) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custum_row_news_item_smal, parent, false);
        } else if (theme.equals("none")) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custum_row_news_item_none, parent, false);
        }
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(FILENAME, 0);
        String theme = sharedPrefs.getString(VAL_KEY7, "little");
        YoYo.with(Techniques.FadeIn).playOn(holder.cardView);
        final FeedItem current = feedItems.get(position);
        holder.Title.setText(current.getTitle());
        holder.Description.setText(current.getDescription());
        if(theme.equals("big")) {
            holder.Date.setText(current.getPubDate());
            Picasso.with(context).load(current.getThumbnailUrl()).resize(150, 100).into(holder.Thumbnail);
        } else if (theme.equals("little")) {
            Picasso.with(context).load(current.getThumbnailUrl()).resize(150, 100).into(holder.Thumbnail);
        }
        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewsDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("Link", current.getLink());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        int size = 0;
        if(feedItems != null){
            size = feedItems.size();
        }
        return size;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView Title, Description, Date;
        ImageView Thumbnail;
        CardView cardView;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
            Description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description_text);
            Date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_text);
            Thumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumb_img);
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more precise about your problem? Why don't you just add the adview?

Comment: I do not know how

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start follow the google tutorial for what you want to use, banner or interstitial ads. The tutorial is pretty understandable. Just use it in the class that should show the ad.

Comment: The problem is not the banner. I do not know how to get it inserted as the second element from the recyclerview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are adding item in your arraylist add null data on second position and in adapter class add the view at second position.

Comment: Thx a lot! It helps